# How can I make bazel depend on Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK?

Tags: java, build, java-8, bazel, build-tools

My platform is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I have already installed JDK 1.8.0_172. However when I install bazel from .sh file, it request me to install openjdk. And when I install it from .deb file, it must to install openjdk from apt repo. Even if the space that open jdk take up is bearable, The conflict of java and javac command in bash window, and the other software which depend java are unavoidable. I am wondering if there is possibility to configure hotpot jdk as default.

How can I make it?

Here is the related website and files:

[Bazel Release in Github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases)

[The .sh installer I used](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.13.0/bazel-0.13.0-without-jdk-installer-linux-x86_64.sh)

[The .deb package I used](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.13.0/bazel_0.13.0-linux-x86_64.deb)

Comment: Where did you download the sh file from? There are multiple versions

Comment: @Ittai, I have already add them at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t an answer to your direct question but I think it might solve your problem (if you’re willing to pay the extra space).
Use the [installer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.13.0/bazel-0.13.0-linux-x86_64) with the jdk bundled inside and I’m fairly confident you shouldn’t have a conflict

Comment: Thanks, there is no conflict.